# Apache flume 1.6.0 compatibility

Tags: flume, rhel7

Can someone help me by saying is apache flume 1.6.0 compatible with RHEL7??

Have tried in apache flume page but not able to find .

Answer (score 0):

The Apache project does not itself test specifically on RHEL7, but it's a Java based app and is designed to run on all Linux. Note also, Cloudera support(ed) Flume on RHEL7, so you should be fairly safe.